# Hacer petición request en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo tres tablas **platos**, **orden**, y **ordenPlatos** relacionadas así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quiero que mi usuario ingrese el numero de la mesa(numMesa) en una vista y que en la vista me muestre una tabla con todos los nombres de los platos que ordenó esa mesa, también la suma del campo "valor" en ordenPlato (solo si pidió más de un plato), luego de debe dar click a un botón que diga cierre que hará que el campo "estado" en la tabla ordenPlato pase de su valor por default "N" a "C".

**Aclaraciones:**

el campo "valor" de la tabla ordenPlato es la multiplicación de la cantidad de platos que ordenó por el precio o "valor" del campo platos. Ya lo tengo calculado automáticamente. Faltaría que se sume con los demás platos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen se ve que para saber el valor total a pagar para la orden con id 5 sería la suma de todos los campos "valor" que hay en la tabla, no necesito almacenarlos, solo mostrarlos.

**EDIT:**

Intenté lo siguiente:

EN el controlador de orden cree un método de cierre() el cual tenia la vista somplemente del formulario el cual solo tenia un input de tipo number el cual el usuario ingresaba el numero de la mesa, luego retornaba una ruta hacia orden.show, donde le pasaba el parametro de numMesa, y funcionaba pero en la vista no supe guardar el valor que pedi el cliente y se me creaban tantos botones como registros tengo en la columna de numMesa.

esto era lo que tenia en la vista.

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Ingrese el número de la mesa:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="numMesa"/>
    </div>

    <a href="{{ route('cierre.show',$ordens->numMesa)}}"
      class="btn btn-primary">Ver</a>
```

y esto era el metodo show()

```
  public function show($id)
    {
         $ordens = Orden::whereHas('plato', function($query) use ($id) {
          $query->whereId($id);
         })
         ->get();
         return view('orden/show', compact('ordens'));
    }
```

aquí están los códigos.

plato migración

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('platos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->char('nombre',50);
            $table->double('valor', 8, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

plato modelo

```
class Plato extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'valor'];


    public function platoingrediente() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\PlatoIngrediente');
}


}
```

ordenPlato migracion

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ordenPlato', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('orden_id');
            $table->foreign('orden_id')->references('id')->on('orden');
            $table->unsignedInteger('plato_id');
            $table->foreign('plato_id')->references('id')->on('platos');
            $table->integer('cantidad');
            $table->double('valor', 8, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

ordenPlato modelo

```
class OrdenPlato extends Model
{
  public $table = "ordenPlato";
  protected $fillable = ['orden_id','plato_id','cantidad','valor'];

  public function orden(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Orden');
  }

  public function plato(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Plato');
  }
```

orden modelo

```
class Orden extends Model
{
    public $table = "orden";
    protected $fillable = ['fecha','numMesa'];


    public function ordenplato() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrdenPlato');
  }
}
```

Comment: @Shassain Porfa, mírate esto por acá, por si me das la mano en esto.

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Necesito hacer la petición, no tengo el código que me haga lo que mencione arriba

Comment: Debes intentarlo primero si quieres que te ayudemos, son las reglas.

Comment: Creo que este articulo te puede ayudar bastante. https://styde.net/nueva-forma-de-validar-peticiones-y-obtener-datos-en-laravel-5-5/

Comment: @Shaz ya edite amigo, puedes verlo.

Comment: Está como un poco largo lo que pides, si lo entiendo bien.

Comment: @Shaz si puedes ayudarme en: Quiero que mi usuario ingrese el numero de la mesa(numMesa) en una vista y que en la vista me muestre una tabla con todos los nombres de los platos que ordenó esa mesa, te lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿Cómo están definidas las dos rutas respectivas? La del formulario donde ingresaría el número de la mesa y la otra donde mostraría los nombres de los platos ordenados.

Comment: Hice un index.blade nuevo, se llama cierre, desde allí tengo el form, y en su controlador tengo un public function index() y pienso mostra la tabla en un show($id) en el mismo controlador.

Comment: Pero no respondiste mi pregunta.